# Can a module have the same name as the package itself when submodules are used?

Tags: python, python-2.7, package, python-module

Currently, I have a package name (let's say DummyPackage). DummyPackage contains three modules with functions, classes, etc. So the directory structure looks like this:

```
project_dir/
    __init__.py
    DummyPackage/
        __init__.py
        Module1/
            __init__.py
            module_x.py
            module_y.py
        Module2/
            __init__.py
            module_z.py
```

So importing methods from modules looks like this

```
from DummyPackage.Module1.module_x import method_x
```

We are adding new stuff to the project and I would like to create a module, with the name DummyProject, which should be importable like this

```
from DummyProject import new_method
```

I assumed, only adding file DummyPackage.py would be enough, but apparently, it's not. I tried to add it to the project_dir/ dir and to DummyPackage/ dir, but neither works.

Is it because of name conflict? Is it possible to have a code like this?

```
import DummyPackage
from DummyPackage.Module1.module_x import method_x

DummyPackage.new_method
method_x
```

Comment: if you added `DummyProject.py` to the `DummyPackage` folder you would import it with `import DummyPackage.DummyProject` would you not?

Comment: or if you were importing it from within `module_x.py` you would use `from ..DummyProject import new_method` see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) for details.

Comment: or if you want `new_method` to be a package level variable you just need to [add some code to your `__init__.py`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18979314/5827215)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to put my three comments in an answer:

First let me explain [relative imports](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) using the modules you already have, if you wanted to import `module_x` from `module_y` you can do this:

module_y.py

```
from .module_x import method_x
```

or similarly in module_z.py

```
from ..Module1.module_x import method_x
```

so depending on the location of your `DummyProject` in the package [Intra-package References](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) may be all you need.

As for the second part yes it is possible to have (runnable) code like this:

```
import DummyPackage
from DummyPackage.Module1.module_x import method_x

DummyPackage.new_method
method_x
```

in this case it looks like you want `new_method` to be a package level variable.  To quote [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18979314/5827215):

> In addition to labeling a directory as a Python package and defining `__all__`, **`__init__.py` allows you to define any variable at the package level.**

I highly recommend taking a look at the source code for `json/__init__.py` in the standard library if you want an real world example.

Or as an example with your setup to be able to import `method_x` right from the package you would just need to add this to the top level `__init__.py`:

```
from .Module1.module_x import method_x
```

then from any file importing the package you could do this:

```
import DummyPackage

DummyPackage.method_x
```

(Although obviously you would do it for `new_method` according to where you place `DummyProject`)

Comment: I tried to add imports to DummyPackage/__init__.py and it works as intented, many thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: [There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)  Although this is only obvious once you understand that `import DummyPackage` really imports `DummyPackage/__init__.py`

Comment: `import json ; print(json.__file__)`